# How quick does this converge to o?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, inequality

Let $a>0$ be fixed and consider the function $f(x) := e^{-ax^2}$, $x>0$. Let $b\in \mathbb{R}$.

It is clear that:
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \left[ e^{-a(h+b)^2}-e^{-ab^2} \right] = 0.$$

My question is actually whether the speed of convergence is of order $h^2$. It is immediate to see that it is at least of order $h$ by a rough application of the mean-value theorem, but I have the intuition that it is even $h^2$, i.e. there is a finite constant $C_{a,b}>0$ independent of $h$ such that:

$$\left| e^{-a(h+b)^2}-e^{-ab^2} \right|\leq C_{a,b}h^2.$$

Any ideas? :)

Thanks!

Comment: $-a(h+b)^2 = -ab^2 -2abh - ah^2$ As $h \to 0$, the $-2abh$ is what counts.

Comment: Yes, then you get $e^{-ab^2}\left( e^{-2abh}e^{-ah^2}-1\right)$. But how can I conclude that the rate is $h^2$ from this? Can I say? $|e^{-ab^2}\left( e^{-2abh}e^{-ah^2}-1\right)| \leq |e^{-ab^2}\left(e^{-ah^2}-1\right)|$ and then use Taylor? but this inequality is only true if $b>0$.

Comment: It isn't (except for $b = 0$), $e^x = 1 + x + O(x^2)$ at $0$, so $e^{-2abh - ah^2} - 1 = -2abh + O(h^2)$.

Comment: Are you 100% it isn't? :O if $b=0$ then it seems to be. Why should that be different?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. For $b = 0$, the linear term in the exponent vanishes, and what remains is $e^{-ah^2} - 1 = -ah^2 + O(h^4)$. For $b \neq 0$, the exponent is $\Theta(h)$ as $h \to 0$, and since $\exp'(0) \neq 0$, it follows that $e^{-a(b+h)^2} - e^{-ab^2} \in \Theta(h)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ e^{-a(h+b)^2}-e^{-ab^2} = e^{-ab^2}(e^{-2abh-ah^2}-1). $$
Now, using Taylor's theorem with the integral form of the remainder,
$$ f(0+h)-f(0) = f'(0)h+\int_0^{h} (h-t)f''(t) \, dt $$
(via integration by parts). Since $f''(t)$ is obviously bounded above on the interval $[0,h]$, the integral is bounded by a finite constant times $h^2$, and hence the convergence is $O(h)$ unless $f'(0)=0$, in which case you can integrate by parts again to find the convergence rate (it's easy to check that this is $O(h^2)$ when $b=0$, i.e. $1-ah^2+o(h^2)$ in this case.